# Extend Firebase Web App to be a Mobile App

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, ionic-framework, firebase

I have been developing a Web App on Firebase and its going great. One of the main reasons I chose Firebase was that it seemed to be able to integrate both mobile and web apps easily - reading and writing to the same database etc.

Now it's time for me to develop the iOS and Android versions of the exact same Web App. **So my question is, how should I best do this?**

Do I base my starting point on my current HTML/JS/CSS or start from scratch? Do I have to go toward ionic (*or something similar?*)? Or is there something really simple within Firebase that I'm missing here?

I have been through all the documentation which really only *hints* at what I need to do. It describes a *project* as:

> a container for apps across iOS, Android and web. It supports sharing of features such as Database, Config and Notifications between your cross-platform apps.  You should add iOS, Android and web app variants to a single project.

Ok, that sounds promising but how to add ***variants*** to my project? I can't see a clear path. Thanks!

Comment: Any updates on this? Did you use a web view on android or integrated firebase separately on web app and android app

Comment: no, unfortunately not. I just made my webApp as mobile-friendly as i could (it was relatively device responsive anyway and left it at that :(   Not my ideal result but workable i suppose